# How to customize method stubs in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I select "Create method ..." in the quickfix menu for a missing method, I want the generated stub to contain the following fragment:

```
// TODO auto-generated method stub
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
```

Is there a setting that will do this?
I'm using 2018 community edition.

I tried modifying "New Method Body" template in "File and Code Templates", to no noticeable effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try modify the Settings / File and Code Templates / "Implemented Method Body" option